# Optimizing MySQL Report Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some queries that are taking over 30mins to execute, I am not a database expert so I really dont know what to so here, I need someone to suggest a better query for:

```
select count(*),substring(tdate,1,7) 
from bills 
where amt='30' 
group by substring(tdate,1,7) 
order by substring(tdate,1,7) desc

SELECT count(*) 
FROM `bills` 
where amt='30' 
and date(tdate)=date('$date') 
and stat='RENEW' 
and x1 in (select `id` from sub);
```

here I pass the value of $date in the following format 'Y-m-d 00:00:00'

```
select count(*),substring(tdate,1,7) 
from bills 
where amt='30' 
group by substring(tdate,1,7) 
order by substring(tdate,1,7) desc
```

Table structures:

```
MariaDB [talksport]> desc bills;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| bid   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| num   | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stat  | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tdate | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| x1    | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amt   | varchar(500) | NO   |     | 30      |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any and all help is welcome.

Michael

Comment: Why are you storing something called `tdate` in a string?  Similarly for something called `amt`?

Comment: that is the transaction date, the date and time the record was inserted into the table

Comment: insert into bills (num,stat,tdate,x1,amt) values('1234','RENEW',now(),'080777','10mt'

Comment: see about data types

Answer (score 1):

Your three queries are really two (the first and third are the same).  These are your three queries (reformatted so they are readable):

```
select count(*), left(tdate, 7)
from bills
where amt = '30'
group by left(tdate, 7)
order by left(tdate, 7) desc;

select count(*)
from `bills`
where amt = '30' and date(tdate) = date('$date') and stat = 'RENEW' and
      x1 in (select `id` from sub);
```

First, you want an index on `bills(amt, tdate)` for the first query.  THe second is more problematic.  In some versions of MySQL, `in` can be an issue.  Also, date arithmetic is problematic.  So, if you are storing `tdate` as YYYY-MM-DD, then pass in `$date` in the same format (better yet, use parameters, better better yet use the right types).  So, I would write this as:

```
select count(*)
from `bills` b
where amt = '30' and tdate = '$date' and stat = 'RENEW' and
      exists (select 1 from sub s where b.x1 = s.id);
```

Then you want an index on `bills(amt, stat, tdate, id)`.

The right indexes should speed your queries.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, one other optimisation that can possibly be done is, replacing `COUNT(*)` by `COUNT(id)`.

When you're counting all the rows and each row has a unique identifier (`id` being the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is already indexed), you would as well get the same `COUNT` if you only counted the ids. The query will have to look for lesser number of columns as well as the one it will sift through will already be indexed to make the searches and aggregations much faster.

It's always good to try and use specific column names instead of `*` in `SELECT` queries. Likewise, always review the columns used in `SELECT` as well as the columns participating in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses to identify the potential candidates for indexing.

**Please note:**
Creating several indexes shouldn't be assumed to be the only method to optimise, as it can possibly slow down bulk `INSERT`s / `UPDATE`s, while attempting to speed up `SELECT` significantly. Besides, you could end up creating indexes that may turn out to be superfluous or redundant. Therefore, a holistic view on application's purpose has to be taken into account to attain an optimal balance - depending on whether more user  operations are concentrated on `INSERT` / `UPDATE` or `SELECT`.